# Failed to parse mapping: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-cloud

I'm having an issue when create index with mapping. It returns "Failed to parse mapping: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters"

- .NET Core version 8.0
- Elasticsearch.Net version 6.8.11
- NEST version 6.8.11

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

please help me this issue, thank you

I can create index without mapping but when i added mapping, it returns error